# How to make nested list operations?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am trying to call nested list operation. I have two different list but Name is their common variable. I have two lists, here's is what i am trying :

1. selectedImage

   ```
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int X { get; set; }
   public int Y { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   ```
2. generatedEyeDistance

   ```
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double eyeDistance { get; set; }
   ```

I want to call generetedEyeDistance's eyeDistance value, however Name should be same. I tried :

```
var asdasf = generatedEyeDistance.Where(f=> (f.Name) == (selectedImage.Select(name => name.Name))).ToList();
```

But this gives following error:

> `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'`

And also my approach looks like wrong. Could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: What result are you expected? Do you want a list of items that contains both sets of properties merged?

Comment: @musefan it should return double.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get generated distances for selected images, then join both collection on Name:

```
from d in generatedEyeDistance
join i in selectedImage
    on d.Name equals i.Name
select d
```

Lambda syntax (I don't like it with joins, but..)

```
generatedEyeDistance.Join(selectedImage, d => d.Name, i => i.Name, (d,i) => d)
```

BTW You have problem, because `selectedImage.Select(name => name.Name)` returns sequence of names, and you are trying to compare sequence with name of distance. Actually you shoul check if there exists image with same name as distance name:

```
generatedEyeDistance.Where(d => selectedImage.Any(i => i.Name == d.Name))
```

But join is much more efficient, because it uses set instead of doing sub-queries for each distance.

UPDATE: One more option, if you have list of distances, and don't want to use query syntax - then you can create set of names and filter list of distances manually:

```
var names = new HashSet<string>(selectedImage.Select(i => i.Name));
var result = generatedEyeDistance.FindAll(d => names.Contains(d.Name));
```

Comment: @musefan nope, it will get filtered list of distances - only those, which was joined with images

Comment: @musefan what makes you think so? OP stated *'I want to call generetedEyeDistance's eyeDistance value'*. Also from code sample you can see OP tries to filter distances

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Sorry but i dont know much about Lambda. Could you help me where should i write this from d in generatedEyeDistance ...... command ?

Comment: @goGud if you need results as list `var asdasf = (from d in .... select d).ToList();`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I see. Now i have small problem. This returns me list(15) which is all same value. However i just want one of them. I dont need list. It should return double with just 1 value.

Comment: @goGud do you have several images with same name or several distances with same name?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy both but i understand the idea now i can manage my items.